# Angular cli routing

Tags: angular, routes

I have a very weird issue where angular does not reload my assets when returning to the main page. It just throws everything out. Can someone please give me some guidance?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question furthermore.

Comment: Sure, so what happens exact:

My main page (home-page) runs perfectly when you refresh or hit it directly, but when I go to different pages and return.... my home page throws out all my layouts and scripts running with the styles.

I dont get any console errors or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the JS had a conflict with JQuery